# Pull out force for a 5/8" tapped bolt

Tags: structural-engineering, steel, threads, bolting, forces

I am looking for the pull out force on a 5/8" bolt tapped into 1/4" thick tube steel.

Does the thickness of the steel need to match or be greater then the bolt diameter?

Comment: You need some idea of the strength of the steel and fastener.

Comment: Thread pitch matters.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:
12,000 lb and not necessarily

Long Answer:
For a rough estimation, let's say you are using a grade 5 bolt and A500 grB tubing, and let's assume your thread engagement length is 1/4".  In this case, the internal threads would strip first at a force of about 12,000 lb.  In reality, it would probably fail sooner since you would only have about 2 or 3 threads to support the force.

If you want to try out this calculation, below are some links you can use (I used a shear stress of 35,000 psi for the tube and 44,000 psi for the bolt).

[Calculation of stressed areas on internal and external threads](https://www.engineersedge.com/thread_strength/thread_bolt_stress.htm)

[Relevant diameters for the area calculation above](http://theoreticalmachinist.com/Threads_UnifiedImperial.aspx)

The thickness of internal threads does not always have to be greater than the bolt diameter, but it's generally better if it is.  That way, the bolt shaft would fail before any threads strip off.  One benefit of this is that it's easier to replace a bolt than to repair damaged threads.  More importantly, if threads start to shear due to excessive torque during installation, it is likely to go unnoticed and then fail during normal operating conditions, which could be a major safety issue.  That being said, it depends on your application, so less threads could be ok in some cases.

On a related note, it may be tempting to increase material thickness when designing a part simply to meet a certain thread engagement, but there are some other options that could be more cost effective or could reduce the final weight.  For example, you could use a [rivnut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkPhGIaPCVs&ab_channel=TechnologyComponents) or a [flow drill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzCBQh8B_RY&ab_channel=FORMDRILL).

Answer (score 0):

A rough guide is that the thickness of the nut or material with the female thread is at least 1 bolt diameter or better at 1.5 times the bolt diameter.

This can vary with the material and the thread pitch amongst other factors.

As for the calculation there are many sites that show this, like engineeringtoolbox.com, however, you can have a go by thinking about the amount of thread surface in contact that takes the load and the strength of both material if they are different.